# Incomplete sd card NTFS formatting. Now it is no more detectable

Tags: filesystem, disk, format, sd-card, fdisk

I was formatting a SanDisk 32 GB SD card to NTFS. It was taking long so I halted it in middle.
Now my SD card is not being detected as an external device anymore, neither in Linux nor in Windows.

But `/var/log/messages` in Linux identifies the device when inserted:

`sudo tail -f /var/log/messages`

```
Nov  7 16:06:27 rakesh kernel: [158863.719308] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB2.0   CARD-READER      1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov  7 16:06:27 rakesh kernel: [158863.720252] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Nov  7 16:06:27 rakesh kernel: [158863.721851] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov  7 16:06:27 rakesh kernel: [158863.740576] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4290192384 512-byte logical blocks: (2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)
Nov  7 16:06:27 rakesh kernel: [158863.744177] sdb: detected capacity change from 0 to 2196578500608
Nov  7 16:06:28 rakesh kernel: [158864.586835] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 39
Nov  7 16:06:28 rakesh kernel: [158864.598069] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
Nov  7 16:06:28 rakesh kernel: [158864.598096]  sdb: unable to read partition table
Nov  7 16:06:28 rakesh kernel: [158864.598107] sdb: partition table beyond EOD, enabling native capacity
Nov  7 16:06:28 rakesh kernel: [158864.598130] sdb: detected capacity change from 2196578500608 to 0
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.333582] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 40 using ehci-pci
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444015] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=5136, idProduct=4678, bcdDevice=10.00
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444028] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444034] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 Device   
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444039] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic 
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444043] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 8120420080429000
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.444775] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh kernel: [158900.445096] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 40: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 40 was not an MTP device
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 40: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Nov  7 16:07:04 rakesh mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 40 was not an MTP device
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.447003] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB2.0   CARD-READER      1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.448068] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.450640] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.474957] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 4290192384 512-byte logical blocks: (2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.478482] sdb: detected capacity change from 0 to 2196578500608
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.513416] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.513433] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.596761] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.596778] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.628841] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.628851] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.720766] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.720784] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.735342] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.735357] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.820765] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Nov  7 16:07:05 rakesh kernel: [158901.820783] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 ff b7 23 80 00 00 08 00
```

also `fdisk` can detect it too.

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LM012 HN-M5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6204f4a1

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 143362047 143360000  68.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       143362048 533987327 390625280 186.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       533989374 976771071 442781698 211.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       533989376 545986559  11997184   5.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       545988608 547176447   1187840   580M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda7       547178496 548366335   1187840   580M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda8       548368384 618115071  69746688  33.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda9       618117120 974755839 356638720 170.1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda10 *    974757888 976771071   2013184   983M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB, 2196578500608 bytes, 4290192384 sectors
Disk model: CARD-READER     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Gparted could see the device too:

[image]

But all fdisk, gparted and any other disk manager software fails to create a new partition table or partion or even format it.

The error message I get is

"I/O error while accessing /dev/sdb"

[image]

If you need me to run a command to see it's output, just mention it in comment section.

Comment: If the SD-card you're trying to format is 32 GB, why does `fdisk` report this: **Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB**?

Comment: I was wondering about the same. I do not know why.

Comment: It may have been taking so long, because of errors. Did you explore why it was taking so long (ie. look in logs for IO errors). It's likely the card is dead, or at least dying, and not worth spending time on..  They don't include validation as are considered a consumable (cheap to produce & replace).

Comment: Chances are higher that your SD card got corrupted.

Comment: Try this command: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M count=2 && sudo sync`. It will erase everything in the beginning of the sd-card, including any corrupted boot records or file systems. **WARNING:** I have used `/dev/sdb` because I assumed the sd-card is on */dev/sdb* indeed. If it's not and you're mistaken, you'll erase another drive. **Make 100% sure it's on /dev/sdb before you execute this command.** Try to create a partition table with `gparted` afterwards and see what happens. If that fails too, your sd-card is probably dead or dying.